# Is every single-valued real function on the set of all positive integers uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

According to the classroom notes "Uniformly Continuous Linear Set" in American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 62. No. 8(Oct., 1955) pp. 579-580, Author: Norman Levine, [DOI: 10.2307/2307254](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2307254)..

How to verify that **every single-valued real function on the set of all positive integers is uniformly continuous??**

Answer (score 4):

Fix any $\delta < 1$. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|x-y| < \delta$ (which, in this case, means x = y) you have
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = 0 < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: sorry for asking you again, In the proof of theorem 1,how to verify that f is continuous while not uniformly continuous itself.

Comment: Uniform continuity means
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0,\ \exists \delta > 0,\ \forall x, y \text{ with } |x-y| < \delta \colon\ |f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon.$$

Now if you put $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{1}{2}$, then this condition is not satisfied: since $p_j \nearrow c$, for any $\delta > 0$ you can choose sufficiently large index $j$ such that $c-\delta < p_j < p_{j+1} < c$ and then
$$|f(p_j)-f(p_{j+1})| = 1 > \varepsilon_0.$$